# Typehint objects within object (stdClass)

Tags: php, oop

I have an instance of stdClass. Each of its properties will be an instance of another class, how do I typehint that?

For reference if it was an array I could use

```
/**
 * @var Other\Class[]
 */
protected $holder;
```

Then I would get typehints for `$mainobj->holder['elem']`. How do I do that with an object?

I tried:

```
/**
 * @var Other\Class{}
 */
```

No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't and I think it's unlikely that any IDE will implement a way to do so, because an object with unknown properties, all of the same type, is not very "OOP like".

> Well it is really a key-value list of instances but I prefer to use stdClass rather than an array - it is prettier and it doesn't require me to use single quotes to access the element which is mainly why I do it this way. I just have to figure out how to typehint that..

That means, you will have to choose between typing a few less characters or having type hints. An associative array is the perfect structure for key-value maps in PHP.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't feel right to me either but it is way more convenient to use object notation, when I click on the property it highlights all other usages, too bad I'm going to have to miss out on that :c

Answer (score 0):

In PhpStorm I use:

```
/** @var Other\Class $variableName */
```

With class properties I leave out the `$variableName`.

Comment: That is going to hint that the property is of type `Other\Class`, no? I need to hint that the properties of this property are of type `Other\Class`.

Comment: Property of a property?  Can't do that, AFAIK.  But I would suggest your property not be a stdClass but a defined class, then typehint there.

Comment: Well it is really a key-value list of instances but I prefer to use stdClass rather than an array - it is prettier and it doesn't require me to use single quotes to access the element which is mainly why I do it this way. I just have to figure out how to typehint that..